# Какие пунктуационные знаки нужны в этом предложении?

Tags: недопустимая-метка, союзы, пунктуация

НУЖНА ЛИ ПЕРЕД СОЮЗОМ И ЗАПЯТАЯ? почему? помогите пожалуйста!
"Трудно было представить, что в этих краях некогда неистовствовала огненная сила и в плане извержений создавались и рушились горы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Трудно было представить, что в этих краях некогда неистовствовала огненная сила и в плане извержений создавались и рушились горы". Перед "и в плане" не нужна запятая, так как имеются общие второстепенные члены "в этих краях некогда", относящиеся к обоим придаточным предложениям. Но при этом мне кажется неудачной фраза "в плане извержений". Лучше написать, например, "при извержениях, от извержений, в результате извержений"